# Rectangle created from mouse x and y not being translated with Graphics2D.translate (other rectangles do)

Tags: java, 2d, mouse, rectangles

I'm making a side-scroller game with survival elements. (kinda like Terraria) When i'm walking to the right, all of the hitboxes and other objects are moved to the left, using Graphics2D.translate() (that's good) but when I use the mouse to click something, it appears that the rectangle/hitbox of the mouse isn't being "translated". I'm sure the problem lays with the rectangle of the mouse because if I remove the two lines of Graphics2D.translate() the digging of blocks work, but you can't walk around freely.

I already tried using the Area object, but also didn't fix it, it was still the same problem.

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle((int)e.getPoint().getX, (int)e.getPoint().getY(), 1, 1);

System.out.println("X: " + (int)e.getPoint().getX());
System.out.println("Y: " + (int)e.getPoint().getY());
bHandler.digBlock(rec); //bHandler is my class BlockHandler:
```

BlockHandler class:

```
public void digBlock(Rectangle rec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < handler.block.size(); i++) {
        Block block = handler.block.get(i);
        if(rec.intersects(block.getBounds())) {
            System.out.println("CLICKED");
            block.setDigging(true);
        }   
    }
}
```

The block.getBounds() method returns a Rectangle.
The block.setDigging(true) will set the Block.digging boolean to true.

What I want is a rectangle that is correctly being translated or/and I want to get the outprint "CLICKED" in my console when I click on a block!

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I think it would be useful if you thought of the display as a window onto your world which has fixed co-ords say 0,0 to 20,20 and as you move the box locations are mapped from the larger world co-ord system to the window frame, that way you never have to translate the mouse location as it is always in the right co-ord system.

Comment: "Rectangle created from mouse x and y not being translated with Graphics2D.translate (other rectangles do)": I dont see any of this stuff here so it's a completely unuseable question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the x variable from my Camera object to the x of my mouse rectangle! Again, thanks for helping!